# Quarkus native build class in both build and run time initialization

Tags: java, quarkus, graalvm-native-image

I have a 3rd party class which is added to build time initialization by Quarkus, but it requires run time initialization due to static thread usage. When adding it to run time initialization native build then complains about it being in both.

Example project which re-produces this: https://github.com/hshorter/quarkus-avro-decode-example

With "--initialize-at-run-time=org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader":

> Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized
>   during image building: org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader
>   the class was requested to be initialized at build time (from the
>   command line).  To see why
>   org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader got initialized use
>   -H:+TraceClassInitialization

Without "--initialize-at-run-time=org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader":

> Error: Detected a started Thread in the image heap. Threads running in
>   the image generator are no longer running at image run time.  To see
>   how this object got instantiated use -H:+TraceClassInitialization. The
>   object was probably created by a class initializer and is reachable
>   from a static field. You can request class initialization at image run
>   time by using the option --initialize-at-build-time=. Or
>   you can write your own initialization methods and call them explicitly
>   from your main entry point. Detailed message: Trace:  object
>   org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just fought through this, in the generated code there's a static initializer like this:
    private static BinaryMessageEncoder ENCODER = new BinaryMessageEncoder(MODEL$, SCHEMA$);
    private static BinaryMessageDecoder DECODER = new BinaryMessageDecoder(MODEL$, SCHEMA$);

We modified the Velocity templates in the Avro code generation to:

1. Add the `@io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.RegisterForReflection` annotation
2. initialize the statics in the constructor using lazy initialization.
3. Remove those classes from the runtime class init. 
   The downside is that you have to maintain your custom codegen templates. It's relatively easy though, here's the maven config to automate your codegen:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${avro.version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>schemas</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>schema</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
 <templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/templates/</templateDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

you can find the base templates at https://github.com/apache/avro/tree/master/lang/java/compiler/src/main/velocity/org/apache/avro/compiler/specific/templates/java/classic

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm late to the party but the issue you have here is that while you asked `SpecificDatumReader` to be initialized at runtime, another class initialized at build time requires `SpecificDatumReader` to be initialized.

So basically, you have some detective work to do to determine why this class was initialized and probably mark the class initializing that one as runtime initialized too.

Note that sometimes it can be a bit hairy.